# Tooltips sometimes appear empty under splite-plot-bands highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm testint information from a page with Selenium Webdriver. I have a graphic like this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands
and I'm having a problem when I try to get the info inside of every dot.
You have to know that this type of highcharts, every dot has the same xpath so, it's impossible to reach to different dots. I can only get one info in one dot.

```
//Click on toolip 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(dot)); 
// action class to click 
Actions action = new Actions((WebDriver) driver); action.click(element).build().perform(); 
String toolTipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tooltip)).getText(); if(!toolTipText.contains(example)) 
sb.append("===> Content error");
```

The problem is that ramdomly, I get empty info from that tooltips. Sometimes I correctly get the info but sometimes it appears empty. Why? Will it be problem because json call? I don't know what could I do...do you have any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance guys!!

Comment: please add your sample code.

Comment: //Click on toolip 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(dot));
// action class to click
Actions action = new Actions((WebDriver) driver);
action.click(element).build().perform();

String toolTipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tooltip)).getText();
if(!toolTipText.contains(example))  sb.append("===> Content error");

Comment: How do you bind data with highcharts?

Comment: I don't know what are you asking me... I didn't make the web page. I am only testing the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking wrong way at highcharts, please refer this [highchart docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart). Highchart is chart plugin that auto render HTML SVG based on highchart options.

To understand problem with tooltip information, you need to look into highchart series data, point objects. point object is contains information related to each dot in chart.

Comment: That code works. I get info from my highchart, but in this case (in this type of graphic with the same xpath in every dots), I sometimes get empty info from tooltip. But the code that I wrote before, works correctly.

Comment: here one problem is that you are looking at each xpath, but highchart tooltip  information bind based on data point that we setup with highchart series. and it will use SVG to render chart. hence, we cannot expect each xpath dot contains information.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what I could do with that information. Sorry. I need help.

Comment: I look at each xpath to get the info, it's correct. An example of xpath under SVG is:

 .//*[@id='highcharts-0']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][5]/*[name()='g'][20]/*[name()='path'][13]

And it works for me. Each dot does contain information.

Comment: I still have the problem, and I am not able to solve it. Could anyone help me, please? I don't know what I could do more. Thanks so much.

Comment: I already said the way you are looking at high-chart is not correct, you should understand the way high-chart is rendering chart, point. and you try to fetch information of point using API methods , please refer this event do that : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click

Comment: Hi @Conqueror I insist that the way I'm looking at high-chart has been correct so far for me. I get info from each dot the same way I said before and I haven't got any problem so far. In this case I don't know what is happening... I've never got empty info...

Comment: Anyway... what would be the correct way to look at the information?

Comment: Would anyone else have an idea? thanx!

Comment: Hi guys!

I still have this problem... I don't know how to solve it... anyone has any idea??

Thanks so much in advance!!!!